# Hiding Axis Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to hide the axis labels on the first subplot at 211.
I'd like to label the figure, not just a subplot (reference: "Isub Event Characteristics").
How can I control font properties like size, font, color?

```
f = Figure()

vdsvgsPlot = f.add_subplot(211)
vdsvgsPlot.plot(theLister()[3],theLister()[0])
vdsvgsPlot.plot(theLister()[3],theLister()[1])

isubPlot = f.add_subplot(212)
isubPlot.plot(theLister()[3],theLister()[2])

plotCanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master)
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(plotCanvas, master)

plotCanvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You have several different questions here... Let me break them up a bit...

By "hide the axis labels on the first subplot" do you mean the actual axis labels (which aren't there unless you specify them), the tick labels (i.e. the numbers along the axis), the axis ticks, or all of the above?

If you mean "all of the above", just do `ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)` and the same for the y-axis.  (`ax` here would be `vdsvgsPlot` in your example code above)

If you mean the axis tick labels, just set them to `[]`, i.e.: `ax.set_xticklabels([])`. (and `set_yticklabels` for the y-axis)

If you mean the axis ticks, you can do something similar: `ax.set_xticks([])` and `ax.set_yticks([])` which will turn off both the ticks and ticklabels.

As to the second question, use [`suptitle`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle) to title the entire figure. i.e.: `fig.suptitle('whatever')` (`f.suptitle...` in your example code above).

As for how to [control the font properties](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-text), you can either pass [various keyword arguments](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/text_props.html#text-properties) to `suptitle` (or anything else that creates text on a plot) or set them after you create the text.  For example `fig.suptitle('This is a title', size=20, horizontalalignment='left', font='Times', color='red')`

In general, I would suggest you look through the various [user's guide](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/index.html), [gallery of examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) (all of which have the source code included), the [pyplot api docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html), and the d[etailed api docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/index.html).

Answer (score 59):

Try using `.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel(None)
plt.ylabel(None)

plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]