# Using an image for tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of small, fixed width images and I want to replace the tick labels with them. For example, consider the following minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

A = np.random.random(size=(5,5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.matshow(A)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to replace the "0" with a custom image. I can [turn off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079795/hiding-axis-labels) the labels, [load an image into an array](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) and display it just fine. However, I'm unsure of

- Where the locations of the tick labels are, since they lie outside the plot.
- Use `imshow` to display that image when it it will be "clipped" if put into an axis.

My thought were to use `set_clip_on` somehow or a custom artist, but I haven't made much progress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question, and potentially has many possible solutions. Here is my approach, basically first calculate where the label `'0'` is, then draw a new axis there using absolute coordinates, and finally put the image there:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pylab as pl

A = np.random.random(size=(5,5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

xl, yl, xh, yh=np.array(ax.get_position()).ravel()
w=xh-xl
h=yh-yl
xp=xl+w*0.1 #if replace '0' label, can also be calculated systematically using xlim()
size=0.05

img=mpimg.imread('microblog.png')
ax.matshow(A)
ax1=fig.add_axes([xp-size*0.5, yh, size, size])
ax1.axison = False
imgplot = ax1.imshow(img,transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]