# Image as axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

Is there a way to keep images as axis values?
Two similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226683/using-an-image-for-tick-labels-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733558/how-can-i-make-the-xtick-labels-of-a-plot-be-simple-drawings-using-matplotlib) does not answer my question.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.catplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", kind="bar", data=titanic)
```

I would like to replace the male and female axis values with the corresponding image present in the image link. Can we map the axis values to the image links?

[image]

Male:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSuGDLqvyU56RbTEFQP3ohzx9d0vJv-nQOk1g&usqp=CAU

Female:
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRnSlVrt4o9yHIHnJ7H-cPi_fhOC4bePnyOoA&usqp=CAU

Comment: Very unclear why those questions don't answer your question. They look like exactly what you're trying to do. Did you try to implement the approach?

Answer (score 2):

The answer using an `OffsetBox` in the questions you linked is probably the best option

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnchoredOffsetbox

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
images = ["https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSuGDLqvyU56RbTEFQP3ohzx9d0vJv-nQOk1g&usqp=CAU",
          "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcRnSlVrt4o9yHIHnJ7H-cPi_fhOC4bePnyOoA&usqp=CAU"]
pos = [0,1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.barplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=titanic)
ax.set_xticklabels([])
for m,p in zip(images,pos):
    image = plt.imread(m)
    im = OffsetImage(image, zoom=0.1)
    ab = AnchoredOffsetbox(loc='upper center', child=im, 
                           bbox_to_anchor=(p,0), bbox_transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),
                           frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]