# Hide axis names/labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a seemingly quite simple question but cannot find an answer anywhere. Python automatically labels the axes with the corresponding column names of the data-frame, which I would like to hide though. I tried the following but the axis label changes to be the string 'None' rather than blank. Is there a right way to do for my purpose? Thanks.

```
import pandas
dat = pandas.DataFrame({'x':[0,1], 'y':[0,1]})
ax = dat.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y')
ax.set_ylabel(None)
```

Comment: Does setting to empty string work? `ax.set_ylabel('')`?

Comment: I think what you're looking for can be found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079795/hiding-axis-labels)

Comment: Thanks. That post is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to disable not the ticker or ticker labels but the name of the the whole axis.

Comment: It is a smart solution to set ' ' as the label. Thanks, EdChum.